# How to style the Audio Tag by HTML5

Tags: html, css, html5-audio

Is there any way to style the Audio Tag? Or more the Audio Tag Controls (for example play button or pause / stop button).

I tried it with `audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button` but that doesn't work.

Comment: No, but you can always write your own player.

Comment: OOPS xD Thank you Adam :) This Post will be deletet instant :)